# explode function in custom function

Tags: php, function, explode

I am trying to create custom function for Main Nav menu where I can only write menu item name and it will automatically wrap with

my content

Also I want variable where I can define url for each menu item.

below is my code and giving me `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE`

```
function the_main_nav($navlinks){
        echo '<nav>';
        echo '<ul>';

        $menuitem = $navlinks;
        $pieces = explode("," $menuitem);
        echo $pieces[0];
        echo $pieces[1];

        echo $menuitem;         
        echo '</ul>';
        return $pieces;
    }
```

------------------[Modified code]----------------------

```
function the_main_nav($navlinks){
echo '<nav>';
echo '<ul>';

$menuitem = $navlinks;
$pieces = explode(" ",$menuitem);
echo '<li>';
    echo $pieces[0];
    echo '</li>';
echo '<li>';
    echo $pieces[1];
    echo '</li>';

echo '</ul>';
    echo '</nav>';      
}
```

Now I want to make it dynamic like instead of getting value from [0] [1]..so on i want it will automatic generate as per the input character and create list with li

Comment: explode("," $menuitem)  ==> explode(",", $menuitem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the `,`. You have to separate the argument of `explode` using comma.

```
$pieces = explode(",", $menuitem);
```

Answer (score 0):

The explode() function breaks a string into an array.
explode(separator, string)
so in your code comma is missing.